# Equivalence of sup-Norm in metric space induced by norm

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

In my textbook I have following definition for the sup-Norm of bounded functions on an arbitrary set $X$ taking values in $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $B(X) := \{\, f \colon X \to \mathbb{C} \mid \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)| < \infty \,\}$:

$$|| \cdot ||_{\infty} \colon B(X) \ni f \mapsto \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)| \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \qquad (\ast)$$
Later in the textbook there occurs the definition of $|| \cdot ||_{\infty}$ for a more general situation again, i.e. if $(Y,|| \cdot ||)$ is a normed space and we define $B(X,Y) := \{\, f \colon X \to Y \mid \sup \{\,d_{||\cdot||}(f(x),f(x^\prime) \mid x,x^\prime \in X\,\} < \infty \,\}$, then author puts

$$|| \cdot ||_{\infty} \colon B(X,Y) \ni f \mapsto \sup \{\, d_{||\cdot||}f(x) ,f(x^\prime)) \mid x,x^\prime \in X\,\}\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \qquad (\ast \ast)$$

where $d_{||\cdot||}(f(x),f(x^\prime)) := ||f(x) - f(x^\prime)||$, i.e. metric induced by the norm $||\cdot||$.

If I choose $(Y,||\cdot||) =  (\mathbb{C},|\cdot|)$, why are equations $(\ast)$ and $(\ast \ast)$ equivalent?

PS: Since the author uses the same symbols for notation, I assume that both equations need to be equal and furthermore the special case shall be included in the more general one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not the same, but by the triangle inequality (via $0$) $\|f\|^{(2)}_\infty \le 2\|f\|^{(1)}_\infty$, where the superscript denotes the first or the second definition. So for most purposes (like (uniform) continuity, etc.) these give the same result.

Comment: This is somehow irritating to me, since I think the textbook I use is really precise on aspects concerning functional analysis. But this seems like a flaw.
You are correct, that I have your stated inequality, but I do not have an inequality $\|f\|^{(1)}_\infty \le C\|f\|^{(2)}_\infty$ for some constant $C > 0$, which would imply that both norms are equivalent. Am I wrong?

Comment: @varsop I see no obvious reverse one, no, but it *is* not too hard to argue that the topologies induced are the same either way.